# Woocommerce change price based on quantity and variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I am currently creating my first site using woocommerce for a client, and they are requesting for me to have a price increase per variation and quantity, however i am not sure how to do it. Here is an example of what they are asking for:

Product Type: Limestone

Variations:

- Product Size:
- - 10kg bag
- - 20kg bag
- - 40kg bag
- Quantity:
- - 1-20

TL;DR
if the customer wants multiple 10kg bags, the price increases by £36 at a time, if they want multiple 20kg bags, the price increases by £30 at a time, and if they want multiple 40kg bags, the price doubles every time.

I have used woocommerce variations and attributes so far but now it would require modifying having 3x20 variations all of which require a different price, which would be easier to change if a statement is possible as follows:

```
if ($productsize === '10kg') {
   $quantity = 2; //get quantity from textbox $_POST
   $initial_price = 36; //get inital price from woocommerce global variable
   
   $total_price = $inital_price * $quantity;

   update_price($total_price); //a function to update the price in woocommerce when adding to cart
   
}
```

Obviously the code above does not use any woocommerce variables, however doing this for only 3 variations would be easier than manually entering 60 variations on one product for which we have >60 on our site.

Comment: This question is unclear. WooCommerce quantity already exist for all products and don't need to set as an attribute variation. each time that you increase the quantity, the price is increased too… Now if you need to set a kind of quantity discount, you don't need to set it on the product itself. You can implement it once products are added to cart…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec At default, whenever i add 1 to the quantity of any item in woocommerce, the price doubles. So if 1x is £36, 2x is £72. However my client wants that if a variation is selected, the price does not double but instead goes up by a fixed amount, dependent on what variation they select. E.g 1x is £36, and 2x is £80 etc.

Comment: You should tell your client he needs to buy [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing](https://woocommerce.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) or similar… To make that yourself is a real development…

Comment: Exactly what i thought. Thanks for your input Loic.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec why cant we do this in our functions.php?

Comment: @BoopathiD Everything is doable in woocommerce depending on the needs, on your skills and on the time that is going to take you...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need it anymore, however try it

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'IG_recalculate_price',5,1 );

function IG_recalculate_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;
    $quantity = 0;


    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            // count q.ty
            $quantity += $value['quantity'];
         // delta q.ty  
        if( $quantity > 24 ) {
           // get price by custom field but you can use a simple var
            $newprice = get_post_meta( $value['data']->get_id(), 'custom_field2', true);
            $value['data']->set_price( $newprice );
           // reset q.ty for check every item in the cart
            $quantity = 0;

                    }else{

            $newprice = get_post_meta( $value['data']->get_id(), 'custom_field', true);
            $value['data']->set_price( $newprice );
            $quantity = 0;

            }
        }
    }
```